# Programmatically Stop AWS EC2 in case of inactivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Can we stop an AWS windows server EC2 instance of a development environment when there is no activity in it, say after 2 hours of inactivity? I am having trouble identifying whether any user is connected to the server virtually.

I can easily start/stop the EC2 at a fixed time, programmatically, but in order to cut the cost of my server, I am trying to stop the EC2 when it is not being used.

**My intent(or use case) is**: If no user is using the EC2 till a specified amount of time, it will automatically stop. Developers can restart it as and when needed.

Comment: What sort of application running in ec2? And how you'll define the idle state? Active connection or some other metrics which are assuming?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/490886/automatically-shut-down-server-on-inactivity-ssh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easiest solution probably would be to set up an Alert with CloudWatch.

Have a [read at the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html), which basically describes your use case perfectly:

> You can create an alarm that stops an Amazon EC2 instance when a
> certain threshold has been met

A condition could be the average CPU utilisation, e.g. CPU utilisation is below a certain point (which most probably correlates with no logged in users / no developer actually utilising the machine).

Comment: This seems to be the best solution to me.  The lambda function above just does the 'stop' action but that is taken care of in cloud watch.  So its a quick no-code solution.  Combine the advice of accept answer to choose cpu utilisaiton < 20% or even 10% over an hour and that should do it.
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/UsingAlarmActions.html

Comment: best answer -- it was trivial to do without any code whatsoever, even the instance-id was available in dropdown, and only a single service, cloudwatch, needed to be configured.

Comment: This works if you have a fixed set of instances and thus have their instance ids. However, it does not work if the developers start new instances regularly.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a simple task.

The Amazon EC2 service provides a virtual computer that has RAM, CPU and Disk. It can view the amount of activity on the CPU, Network traffic and disk access but **it cannot see into the Operating System**.

So, the problem becomes **how to detect 'inactivity'**. This really comes down to the operating system and making some hard decisions. For example, your home computer screen turns off after a defined time of no mouse/keyboard input but the operating system is still doing activity in the background. If the system is running an application such as a web server, and there are no web requests, it is hard to know whether this is 'inactive' because there are no requests, or 'active' because the web server is running.

**Bottom line:** There is no out-of-the-box feature to do this. You would need to find your own definition of 'inactivity' and then trigger a shutdown in the Operating System.

If you wish to do it via schedule, this might help: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: That was my opinion reading your question. But if you want AWS to handle that, and not your EC2, you can take your logs out to CloudWatch, analyze them and trigger events.

Comment: CloudWatch can only provide CPU Utilization, Network and Disk access. In my opinion, that alone is not sufficient to decide on 'inactivity'. But, I agree that it might be possible to analyze past metrics, look at patterns during times of activity and times of inactivity, and then potentially make a decision. Frankly, it would be easier for a program running on the instance itself to detect 'activity', since it would have access to richer data.

Comment: Still agree, CPU / RAM is not "inactivity". I meant CloudWatch Logs. It can be used as a log centralization tool to monitor logs and trigger alarms handled by Lambda. Just in case someone really need to handle this analysis outside the EC2.

Comment: This is a simple task in most situations, but it is not simple if you want to generalize it. Most use cases can detect using average CPU or average network or average I/O over a time period.

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATE: Lambda's aren't needed anymore, see tpschmidt's answer.*

Create a Lambda to turn off the EC2 that will be triggered by a Cloud Watch Alarm when for example the CPU goes under 20% average for an hour. This is fine when you're coding as you will be using more than 20%, and when you have a break for over an hour that's when you want it turned off.

Be sure to set auto save in your IDE's.

Example Python Lambda:

```
import boto3
region = 'eu-west-3'
instances = ['i-05be5c0c4039881ed']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #TODO getInstanceIDFromCloudWatch = event["instanceid"]
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

Ref: https://www.howtoforge.com/aws-lambda-function-to-start-and-stop-ec2-instance/

In AWS Console:

1. Goto EC2, select the EC2 instance and copy the Instance ID
2. Goto Cloud Watch and select Metrics
3. Under AWS Namespaces click EC2
4. Paste the Instance ID to find it
5. Select EC2 > Per-Instance Metrics
6. Choose the first metric CPU utilisation
7. Select the second tab called Graphed Metric
8. Click the Bell icon under Actions
9. Set a threshold, also this is the hard part, leave the default of Statistic: Average over 1 hour
10. Set the Condition Lower/Equal and put the value as 20% (you'll need to use the machine more than 1/5th of the hour over 20% CPU otherwise it'll turn off).
11. Next create an alarm, setup a notification if you like or remove it
12. Once the Alarm is created
13. In Cloud Watch select Event > Rules
14. Add a Rule
15. Select EC2 as the Service Name and All Event
16. Click Target and select your Lambda.
17. When the Alarm goes off the Lambda will turn off the instance ID

Comment: lambda functions are not needed; can be done entirely in cloudwatch with point-and-click. see answer by @tpschmidt below

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for adding stop action to your ec2 instance, this can be easily achieved using CloudWatch alarms.
You can do this from the console using the following steps:

1. Open the [Amazon EC2 console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/)
2. In the navigation pane, choose **Instances**.
3. Select the instance and choose **Actions, Monitor and troubleshoot,
   Manage CloudWatch alarms**.

   Alternatively, you can choose the plus sign (  ) in the **Alarm status**
   column.
4. On the **Manage CloudWatch alarms** page, do the following:

   - Choose to **Create an alarm**.
   - To receive an email when the alarm is triggered, for **Alarm
     notification**, choose an existing Amazon SNS topic. You first need to
     create an Amazon SNS topic using the Amazon SNS console. For more
     information, see Using Amazon SNS for application-to-person (A2P)
     messaging in the Amazon Simple Notification Service Developer Guide.
   - Toggle on the **Alarm actio**n, and choose **Stop**.
   - For **Group samples by** and **Type of data to sample**, choose a statistic
     and a metric. In this example, choose **Average** and **CPU utilization**.
   - For **Alarm When** and **Percent**, specify the metric threshold. In this
     example, specify **<=** and 10 percent.
   - For the **Consecutive period** and **Period**, specify the evaluation period for
     the alarm. In this example, specify 1 consecutive period of 5
     Minutes.
   - Amazon CloudWatch automatically creates an alarm name for you. To
     change the name, for the **Alarm name**, enter a new name. Alarm names must
     contain only ASCII characters.
   - Choose to Create.

> Note You can adjust the alarm configuration based on your own
> requirements before creating the alarm, or you can edit them later.
> This includes the metric, threshold, duration, action, and
> notification settings. However, after you create an alarm, you
> cannot edit its name later.

Check this [link from the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html#:%7E:text=Choose%20Create.-,Add%20terminate%20actions%20to%20Amazon%20CloudWatch%20alarms,-You%20can%20create) for terminating the instance using the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an AWS **Cloudwatch alarm** that monitors activity. Different parameters like **ComparisonOperator, Period, and Threshold** can be modified according to how you want to monitor your Ec2 instance.

Then, you can set up an SQS queue and set a Python Lambda function as its target. Within the lambda function, you can use boto3 to turn off the ec2 instance. You can read more details here: https://medium.com/geekculture/automatically-turn-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-31fedd363cad

Terraform setup:

https://medium.com/geekculture/terraform-setup-for-automatically-turning-off-ec2-instances-upon-inactivity-d7f414390800

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for adding stop action to your ec2 instance, this can be easily achieved using CloudWatch alarms.

Here, I will show how to do that using **Terraform**:

```
    resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "ec2_cpu" {
    alarm_name                = "StopTheInstanceAfterInactivity"
    metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
    comparison_operator       = "LessThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    statistic                 = "Average"
    threshold                 = var.threshold
    evaluation_periods        = var.evaluation_periods # The number of periods over which data is compared to the specified threshold
    period                    = var.period # Evaluation Period (seconds)
    namespace                 = "AWS/EC2"
    alarm_description         = "This metric monitors ec2 cpu utilization and stop the instance if it is inactive"
    actions_enabled           = "true"
    alarm_actions             = ["arn:aws:automate:${var.region}:ec2:stop"]
    ok_actions                = [] # do nothing
    insufficient_data_actions = [] # do nothing
    dimensions                = {InstanceId = aws_instance.ec2_instance.id}
}
```