# Stop ec2 instance after 5 minutes with sleep - time.sleep() not working as expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I have the following piece of code running in lambda.  I want to stop my EC2 instance, after 5 minutes.  For this i have used time.sleep to have a interval of 5 minutes before issuing stop_instance command.  But the code does not pass after the time.sleep, and instead loops the lambda script from beginning?

```
 ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
 resp = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=instances)
 if(len(resp['InstanceStatuses']) == 0):
          ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
          print("Started instance with Instance_id : ",instances)
    else:
        instance_status = resp['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Code']
        if instance_status == 80:
            ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
            print("Started instance with Instance_id : ",instances)
            print("Instance staus - 1 **: ",instance_status)

    status = 0
    counter = 5
    while (status != 16 and counter > 0):
        resp = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=instances)
        if len(resp['InstanceStatuses']) != 0:
            status = resp['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Code']
            time.sleep(5)
            counter=counter-1
            print("Instance staus - 3 **: ",status)

    print("Wait for 5 minutes please !!!")
    i = 0
    while (i < 1):
       time.sleep(300)
       i = i + 1

    print("Wait time is over, instance status : ", status)
    resp = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=instances)
    instance_status = resp['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Code']
    
    print("Instance staus - 2 **: ",instance_status)
    if instance_status == 16:
        #check if file exists in the S3 location, and if yes, then stop instances.
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
        print("Stopped instance with Instance_id : ",instances)
```

This is what i see in my cloudwatch logs, and the instance is not STOPPED.  Following is how my cloudwatch log is :

[image]

Can someone help me how to get this done, so as to stop the ec2 after x minutes.  Thanks.

Comment: Lambda functions have a maximum execution time, which is likely less than five minutes.

Comment: @AKX it's been increased from 5 to 15 mins - at the date of writing.

Comment: What is your _actual_ goal? That is, what are you trying to achieve? Do you want an EC2 instance to stop _x_ minutes after launching? If so, it is best for the instance to shutdown itself via a simple shell script. Please let us know _what_ you're trying to achieve and _why_ (rather than _how_) and we will possibly be able to suggest a better method.

Answer (score 0):

Why even bother with the While when you only call it once. Just remove the `While`

A better way is to setup a UserData EC2 script that either:

A) saves a .py file to the machine (off S3) and execute it to turn off the machine in 5 mins. Or

B) a bash/PowerShell `timer.sleep(300)` in the UserData.

**Edit**

Can you simply convert this to Bash/PowerShell and put it in the UserData?

```
time.sleep(300) 
print("Wait time is over, instance status : ", status) 
resp = ec2.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=instances) 
instance_status = resp['InstanceStatuses'][0]['InstanceState']['Code'] 
print("Instance staus - 2 **: ",instance_status)
 if instance_status == 16:
   ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, initially i was trying without the while loop and it had the same issue.  Then i referred to some SO responses where it was suggested to have while or if condition.  Wondering why it should start from the beginning of the lamda script.

Comment: Any i was expecting if the while loop fails when i = 1 or greater than 1, then it would proceed to the next line, which is printing, "Wait time is over, instance status ..", which is not happening.

Comment: Maybe timers in Lambda are banned after a certain time out as people try to abuse keeping their lambdas warm. See this, I think the Cloud Watch events are called EventBridge now so those instructions may be out of date but you get the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63166951/495455

Comment: Thanks.  I already have an ML python script in user data, which runs while the EC2 is starting.  I just want to give some time of 5 minutes, so the python script completed fully, and uploads a file to S3.  Without the sleep if i simply add the STOP INSTANCE, the python script in userdata is not completely run, and I miss the output file in S3.